# how to remove duplicated data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

i have proplem with return data without duplicate

i need to get com_id with maximum date without duplicate in com_id and i need to show com_id's order by t_date

**

### don't care about current_season and season this is another thing i just need to get com_id of maximum date without duplicate com_id order by t_date

**

---

[image: i have this view in db]

> i tried this code but i got a wrong result

`SELECT com_id
FROM vw_vsa
where current_season=season
GROUP BY com_id,t_date
order by t_date`

my expected result is

124235623  (month 1)
123457     (month 1)
1111  (month 2 (maximum month of his group)
123   (month 5 (maximum month of his group)

Comment: what is the expected result ?

Comment: just com id's order by t_date .. but t_date of distinct com_id must be maximum of his group

Comment: please update your question and show the expected result

Comment: I updated it help me if you can

Comment: looking at the expected result looks like you just wanted `SELECT distinct com_id
FROM vw_vsa
where current_season=season`. Not sure about the implication of your requirement : `get com_id of maximum date`. If it does matter, please elaborate with more example

Comment: look I'm sorry about complication ... look at com_id it duplicate and has a t_date i need to get maximum t_date of every single (unique)com_id and then order the result from min to max In terms of t_date

Comment: ` order the result from min to max In terms of t_date` in terms of `t_date` or the month of `t_date` ?

Comment: actually I said from min to max and that's mean from older date to newest date.. so not just a month and the day of month ... i can give ex. >> 1/1/2019 then 2/1/2019 then 2/2/2019 then 5/20/2019 (format is month/day/year)

Comment: then your expected result is misleading. You should not have stated `(month 1)` etc. And why `1111` comes after `124235623` ? when the date for `1111` is 2018 and `124235623` is 2019 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on your description, the `order by` should be just `max(t_date)`. But expected result, it looks like you wanted to order based on `month`

```
SELECT com_id, max(t_date)
FROM   vw_vsa
where  current_season = season
GROUP BY com_id
order by month(max(t_date))
```

Comment: that's true but just one proplem that day of the month ,,, i means i need to get 2/2/2019 firstly then 2/1/2019

Comment: just change the `ORDER BY` clause accordingly to your requirement

Comment: thank you it's worked and I'm sorry about complication

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to do this:

```
SELECT com_id, max(t_date)
FROM vw_vsa
where current_season=season
GROUP BY com_id
order by max(t_date)
```

Comment: nice but dates of all com_id's were not orderd from min to max

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `DISTINCT` at from of the `clasule`

```
SELECT DISTINCT com_id FROM vw_vsa where current_season=season GROUP BY com_id,t_date order by t_date
```

Comment: i got this error  ... ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.